# Cannot assign []byte to z (type string) in multiple assignment

Tags: string, go, byte

I'm trying to find the contents of files within a folder, so I'm listing what's in the folder then while looping through it I'm trying to read the files.

```
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("documents/")
for _, f := range files {
        //fmt.Println(f.Name())

    z := "documents/" + f.Name()
    fmt.Println(z) // prints out 'documents/*doc name*' recursively
    z, err := ioutil.ReadFile(z) // This line throws up the error
```

The error I get is: test.go:85: cannot assign []byte to z (type string) in multiple assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert `[]byte` to string, but you cannot convert one value of a multiple return valued function.

```
buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(z)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
z = string(buf)
```

However, quite often it's better to *not* convert binary data to strings and work directly with `buf`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!
I noticed you used '=' rather than ':=', why is that?

Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Patrick `=` is used when you declare your variable like this `var x []string` this is declaring a variable of this type; whereas, `:=` is the same thing (declaring a variable) just letting the compiler decide the type of the variable so you don't have to type it explicitly .  Note `:=` this can only be done within a function. http://tour.golang.org/#12

Comment: @Patrick: It's a short variable declaration. It is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types. See [Short variable declarations, The Go Programming Language Specification.](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)